# Methods of determining if a non-primitive polynomial is irreducible in a ring

Tags: ring-theory

Take, for example, $ X^4 + 2X + 2 $ in $ \mathbb{Q}[X] $. How do I determine if this is irreducible?

Thoughts:

I know Gauss' Lemma and Eisenstein's criterion, but they only work for primitive polynomials.

Comment: What do you mean by "primitive" here? If you mean "the gcd of the coefficients is $1$", then this polynomial *is* primitive.... And you can take any polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and convert it to a primitive polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$ (by suitably multiplication by constants); the original polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if the resulting one is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) works for proving that non-primitive polynomials are irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. One then might hope to use [Gauss's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29#Formal_statements) to prove that a polynomial with integer coefficients which is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is also irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, which then requires primitivity. So, because

- $2$ doesn't divide $1$ (coefficient of $x^4$)
- $2$ divides $0$ (coefficient of $x^3$)
- $2$ divides $0$ (coefficient of $x^2$)
- $2$ divides $2$ (coefficient of $x$)
- $2$ divides $2$ (coefficient of $1$)
- $2^2=4$ doesn't divide $2$ (coefficient of $1$)

by Eisenstein's criterion the polynomial $x^4+2x+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

In fact, the polynomial $x^4+2x+2$ is primitive, since $\gcd(1,0,0,2,2)=1$, so the polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ too.

Comment: Thanks. What about something like $X^4 + 1 $?

Comment: $x^4+1$ is a bit trickier, but it is actually still possible to use Eisenstein's criterion here. Here is a hint: if $f(x)$ is irreducible, what other polynomials can you deduce are irreducible?

Comment: I can make linear substitutions for the variable. So here, x = 1 + y works. I'm struggling to find a substitution to make for $ x^3 - 9 $ though. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @user938272: Why should one try to find a substitution that allows us to apply the Eisenstein Criterion to $x^3-9$? This is a cubic, and a cubic is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ iff it has no rational root.

Comment: @user6312: you are absolutely right but there is a little caveat: you have to prove that $9$ is not a cube in $\mathbb Q$. It is easy but has to be done.